# Is it possible to enable GuardMalloc and Zombie Objects while running an App from command line?

Tags: xcode, macos, memory-management, crash, xcode-instruments

Is it possible to enable GuardMalloc and Zombie Objects while running an App from command line?

If I could set some kind of environment Variables to enable these before running app?

Answer (score 0):

**NSZombies**
You can use the `NSZombieEnabled` environment variable: `NSZombieEnabled=YES`.

**Guard Malloc**
Set the `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` environment variable to `/usr/lib/libgmalloc.dylib`. This tells dyld to use Guard Malloc instead of the standard version of malloc. See the [libgmalloc man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/3/libgmalloc/) for more details.

You can find additional envars to configure the behavior here: [Configuring the Malloc Environment Variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html)